# How to convert gwt app to fb?

Tags: facebook, gwt

I developed a GWT app and hosted in Google app-spot, i would like to know is there any way i can convert/transfer it into a Facebook apps?
Or is it possible for to develop Facebook apps on GWT?
Be frank to tell me what you think and know about these things.. 
Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is Possible .
Java script is meant for Browser and ultimately your GWT code will convert into javascript .

Your javascript code will dispaly on the facebook apps entry point page "Canvas Page ".

So it is possible

For a quick example of facebook app

http://gathadams.com/2007/06/18/how-to-write-a-facebook-application-in-10-minutes/

All the best .